# Remove Annotations in Subclass?

Tags: java, annotations

i have a child Class, that needs an Annotation, that is declared in the Parent class removed. What is the best way to do this?

```
public class Parent

@MyAnnoation
String foobar;

}


public class Child extends Parent {
//here I only want to remove the @MyAnnotation from String foobar;

}
```

What I want to avoid is, "overriding" the member

```
 public class Child extends Parent {

 String foobar;

 }
```

as this has several disadvantages (as it "covers" the underlaying parent member = this.foobar can be different to super.foobar)...

1.) Is there an easy way of removing an annotation from a Parent Class in the Subclass (here Child)?

2.) What is the official way to remove annotations in a Subclass?

Thanks very much! Markus

Comment: if you want to do something like this than you probably should have another look at your design. I think that if there is a way to remove a runtime annotation than that would not be recommended :)

Comment: @SurajChandran Your question is like: "Why would you want to override a method ?". Answer: well, because that's what Object Oriented Programming is about. You specify something at a super class, and then you modify it in a subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do something like this than you probably should have another look at your design.

I think that if there is a way to remove a runtime annotation than that would not be recommended, because you would be remove a part of a class definition. Like removing a member access modifier for instance.

That can have unexpected results on your logic since other code might rely on these definitions to make runtime decisions.

If you need to modify a class definition during runtime than this class should probably not be defined in such a way in the first place.

Comment: +1 - Extending because a class is "a bit like" rather than "is a" is wrong.

Comment: So, if the parent class defines a method to be `@Nullable`, and after overriding it, that method is no longer nullable, then shouldn't you be able to remove that annotation ? :) I mean, it sounds a lot less convincing now, doesn't it ? - Okay, Nullable is not a runtime thing, but I think this holds for all annotations (i.e. meta) Meta DOES change when you overrule methods.

Comment: @bvdb can you give an example where a child's field is the same field and and can be null? If we have, say a house, and a house is not a house without a roof, then the roof is not nullable. I can't think of an inheritor of a house that is a house, but has no roof.

Comment: My point is that "more-general" definitions reside in parents and children should not override them. If they need to, this usually means the parent definition needs to be revised.

Comment: @Simeon , Good example, Let's say in 2016 we write a class `House` with a `@NotNull Roof getRoof()` method. It's part of a public API (a `.jar` file), and 1M people download and use this class. Then in 2020 a building company starts to build plastic houses in spheral shapes, a house without a roof. - Now you couldn't know there would be subclasses for your house. That's ok. The parent class can't/shouldn't be responsible for the crazy behavior of its child classes, should it?

Comment: If I'm correct, your proposal is to revise the parent class in such a case. But that would break compatibility for those million existing users who don't even need `@Nullable roofs` and who already wrote a lot of code under the assumption that a `House` has a `@NotNull roof`. - In reality: Luckily you can redefine this `@Nullable` on the child class, so it's not a real problem here. --- My point is: I think the designer of the parent class isn't responsible (he couldn't know) and the child class designer just faces reality. I don't blame them, I blame the poor JLS, which lacks features.

Comment: @bvdb Yes, it unfortunately would break compatibly, I agree. That's way design of the general stuff is very tricky and that's why newer libraries use things like, `@BetaApi` (Guava for instance), `@ExperimentalApi` and such, so that users/3rd-party-implementers, know that the API can change and break their client implementations. I was answering mostly in the perfect-world scenario, where you implement your own API and you can "break" it for "more correctness". I completely agree that there will be cases where you can't revise the parent. In those cases all hacking is mostly justified :)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can't remove annotations. But this may help:

1. Not all annotations are available at runtime. So, in that case obviously there's no reason to remove them. Only annotations with a `@Retention(RUNTIME)` are available at runtime. (e.g. `@Nullable` annotations are not available at runtime, but `@XmlElement` is.).
2. **Only for class-level annotations**, there's another thing to take in account. Not all annotations are inherited automatically to child classes. This is only the case for annotations which have an `@Inherited` annotation of their own.
3. Some annotations can be contradicted by redeclaring a different annotation. (e.g. a parent class with `@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)` can have a child class with `@XmlAccessorType(PUBLIC)`.)

So, removing is impossible, but redefining/replacing is. **In practice that means that the effect of some annotations can be "removed" by setting them to their default value `@MyAnnotation(NONE)` or `@MyAnnotation(DEFAULT)` or `@NotMyAnnotation`.** So, that means it really depends what kind of annotations you are dealing with.

*One more thing: Even though you can redefine annotations on child classes, still it doesn't always give the desired effect. (e.g. In the case of `@XmlElement` sometimes the annotation on the parent method still has priority during execution). It's good to know that some frameworks (e.g. persistence) support alternative xml binding files as an alternative to java class annotations).*